# Why do I need to wrap the list items in a Column in order to dynamically add items using a button to ListView Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

For the past day, I had a hard time coming up with a simple piece of code just to add some items to a ListView using a button. I wanted to create a list in my app and add items to this list simply by clicking a FloatingActionButton.
The problem was that when I clicked the button, nothing happened. But then when I HotReloaded the app, items magically appeared in the list (code block 1).
After some research, I found a simple solution that worked perfectly. I just wrapped the items in a **Column** widget and everything worked fine. But I cannot explain why. How is this working? What part of my initial code was wrong? Is this related to how the `setState()` method works? How does `setState()` work exactly??

*My initial code:*

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<Widget> items = [
    Text('initial txt'),
  ];

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      items.add(Text('NewText'));
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),

      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: ListView(
                children: this.items,
              ),
              width: 100,
              height: 400,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            )
          ],
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 10, 20, 10),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

*Second Code:* Just created a temp list in `_incrementCounter()` function and assigned it to the old list in `setState()` (Why should I do it like this?) and wrapped the **items** in a Column widget.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<Widget> items = [
    Text('initial txt'),
  ];

  void _incrementCounter() {
    List<Widget> ls_tmp = this.items;
    ls_tmp.add(Text('New Text $_counter'));

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
      this.items = ls_tmp;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),

      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: this.items,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              width: 100,
              height: 400,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            )
          ],
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 10, 20, 10),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

And last but not least, any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of buried in the documentation, but you can find it here:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.html

> Like other widgets in the framework, this widget expects that the children list will **not be mutated after** it has been passed in here. See the documentation at [SliverChildListDelegate.children](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverChildListDelegate/children.html) for more details.

In Android Studio, if you hover over `children:`, then it will show this same documentation.

Instead, you need to use a `ListView.builder`:

```dart
child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return items[index];
  },
),
```